# Simple VBA code to copy sheet causes "Microsoft Excel has Stopped working"

Tags: excel, vba

I checked the 1st 45 other questions regarding “Excel has stopped working”. None of the ones with answers helped me. Apparently, a lot of different things can cause this problem.

I have a workbook with 59 sheets, but I only need a dozen of them. I wrote a simple macro that inspects the name of each sheet and if the name contains “H2O” or “NG”, the sheet is copied to another workbook I previously created and have open when the macro runs. The first attempt to copy a sheet results in Excel shutting down and restarting, accompanied by the “Microsoft Excel has stopped working” message.

The workbook has a lot of sheets, but it has no Form or Active-X controls or formulas on any sheet, no forms, and only the one macro shown below. I could copy the sheets manually or change the macro to hide the sheets I don’t want, but I’m getting the same error with a more complicated macro that copies a single sheet from each of 39 workbooks in different folders to a single workbook with 39 sheets, so I’d really like to know what’s causing this. 
I’m running Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus with Windows 10 version 1709. The macro always encounters an "NG" sheet first so the line of code that causes the problem is always the one after 'Case is = "NG"':

'Sheets(SheetName).Copy After:=Workbooks("Gas History Henry Mayo.xlsx").Sheets(GasSheetCount)'

```
Sub CreateWaterAndGasWorkbooks()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim SheetType As String
    Dim WaterSheetCount As Integer
    Dim GasSheetCount As Integer
    WaterSheetCount = 1
    GasSheetCount = 1

    With Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
       SheetName = Sheets(i).Name
       SheetType = ""
       If InStr(1, SheetName, "H2O") > 0 Then SheetType = "Water"
       If InStr(1, SheetName, "NG") > 0 Then SheetType = "NG"
       .Cells(i, 1).Value = SheetName 'Just for debug, so I know where
       .Cells(i, 2).Value = SheetType 'I was if it bombs.
       Select Case SheetType
       Case Is = "Water"
          Sheets(SheetName).Copy After:=Workbooks("Water History Henry Mayo.xlsx").Sheets(WaterSheetCount)
          WaterSheetCount = WaterSheetCount + 1
          Windows("Utility Cost Spreadsheets.xlsx").Activate
       Case Is = "NG"
          Sheets(SheetName).Copy After:=Workbooks("Gas History Henry Mayo.xlsx").Sheets(GasSheetCount)
          WaterSheetCount = GasSheetCount + 1
          Windows("Utility Cost Spreadsheets.xlsx").Activate
       Case Else
       'do nothing
       End Select
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me see that I didn’t make my question clear. I wasn’t asking what “Excel has stopped working” means. I was asking why does this straightforward code that seems like it should work cause that outcome. I thought a simple declarative that some code causes Excel to choke would be enough, but I should have said WHY does this code do it. My push for brevity cost me clarity. Still, if I was reading a post like mine, I wouldn’t think the poster didn’t understand what the message means. I'll use this experience to phrase my question better when I repost on another site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the shorter version below, without using any `Activate`.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWaterAndGasWorkbooks()

Dim WaterSheetCount As Long
Dim GasSheetCount As Long

Dim WaterWb As Workbook
Dim GasWb As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

' set the Water workbook object
Set WaterWb = Workbooks("Water History Henry Mayo.xlsx")

' set the Gas workbook object
Set GasWb = Workbooks("Gas History Henry Mayo.xlsx")

WaterSheetCount = 1
GasSheetCount = 1

' loop through all sheets
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    Select Case True ' "cheat" a little
        Case Sht.Name Like "*H2O*"
            Sht.Copy After:=WaterWb.Sheets(WaterSheetCount)
            WaterSheetCount = WaterSheetCount + 1

        Case Sht.Name Like "*NG*"
            Sht.Copy After:=GasWb.Sheets(GasSheetCount)
            WaterSheetCount = GasSheetCount + 1

        Case Else
            'do nothing

    End Select
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, Thank you for taking the time to think about my issue and write some alternative code. Sadly, I get the same result. I don't think our code is "wrong". I think it's a consequence of Excel being a complex program with millions of lines of code running in an even bigger & more complex Win10. You're about not needing the time-wasting Activate stmt. I started with macro recorder & when you do it manually you have to get back to the source workbook. I like your use of Like to shorten the process of finding the right sheets, so I got a useful tip even though the issue remains unsolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although the error occurred while using VBA, I suspected it was not because anything was wrong with the code itself. I kept searching and finally came across a recommendation to disable Excel Add-Ins. I disabled 2 of them (Name Manager Utility & Find Link) and now both my original code and the improved version contributed by Shari Rado work.

I found 6 discussions of "Excel has stopped working" at StackOverflow, all with different circumstances (but mostly involved with opening or closing workbooks) & read 45 answers. No one suggested disabling Add-ins. So, if you're one of those people like Shai who try to help folks who post problems here, you should add that approach to your bag of tricks. Here's where I found the answer that worked for me:

https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-microsoft-excel-stopped-working-error/

Comment: Not to nitpick, but **there are a lot more than 6 questions about "Excel Stopped Working" on this site**.  Many more.  In fact, almost none of the Excel questions on this site are because "Excel is working fine."  ...my point is, the reason you *only* found what you did is because your terminology and problem description need to be more specific and accurate."Stopped Working" doesn't mean *anything* useful when it comes to solving a problem and there's likely more information that could be provided.  (A screenshot at the very least.)

Comment: It might be a good idea to brush up on advanced search tips for Google, [so] and other sites. (I don't mean that insultingly; In my opinion theory that "Effective Googling Skills" should be mandatory first class for any programmer.)  Exact wording & multiple variations should also be tried. **[This verbatim Google search for `"Microsoft Excel has stopped working"` (with quote) returns 600+ pages with the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22microsoft+excel+has+stopped+working%22&num=100&tbs=li:1&filter=0)**. Add `site:stackoverflow.com` to the search terms to see **only the 80 on [so]**.